# The closures in $C^0(\mathbb C,\mathbb C)$ of the set of integer valued polynomials

Tags: polynomials, approximation-theory

This question is closely related to the thread [The closures in $C^0(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ of the set of integer valued polynomials, resp, of polynomials with integer coefficients.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/50657/the-closures-in-c0-mathbbr-mathbbr-of-the-set-of-integer-valued-polyn?rq=1) (Recall that a polynomial $p$ is called *integer valued* if $p(n)\in\mathbb Z$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$.)

I would like to know if 
the closure of integer valued polynomials in $C^0(\mathbb C,\mathbb C)$ is the set of complex continuous functions that take integer values on integers.

The arguments on the already cited thread do not seem to generalize easily.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: Two trivial remarks: (1) If $p:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$, then $p$ has real coefficients; (2) if $p_n\to f$ locally uniformly, then $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Does "polynomial" here mean "holomorphic polynomial", i.e. a polynomial in $z$, or is $\bar{z}$ an integer valued polynomial?

Comment: Polynomials means here "polynomials in $z$ only"

Comment: Christian; What you said means the closure of $\mathrm{Int}(\mathbb N,\mathbb Z)$ in $C^0(\mathbb C,\mathbb C)$ is at most the set of continuous functions on $\mathbb C$ that takes integer values on $\mathbb N$ whose restriction is real valued on $\mathbb R$. So now the question is: are the sets equal?

Comment: Actually what he's saying is that the closure (wrto local uniform convergence on   $\mathbb{C}$) of the set of the complex polynomials mapping $\mathbb{Z}$ into itself, is included in the set of real entire  functions mapping $\mathbb{Z}$ into itself.

Comment: @joaopa : Yes, this class (= see Pietro's comment) seems to be the natural conjecture (at least without thinking about it too hard). I think your question is interesting, but please modify the second paragraph accordingly.